Adb can't find the provider when using root but give permission error when using unroot
I've just start using adb and I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem.
I have a provider which is exposed but does have some permissions like write or read
so when I do adb shell content call --uri "content://providername"
I get this
Error while accessing provider:com......
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.....from (null) (pid=x, uid=2000) requires **com.......read** or **com.......write**

this makes senses because I don't have the permissions to access the provider
but when a use abd root I start having a weird behavior :
Error while accessing provider:com......   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find provider:   which doesn't make sense at all .
any idea why and how can I access the provider with adb and have the permissions . thanks
I've tried to change the config in the emulator and also play with the syntax but no result
